# jQuery usage of .filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am currently learning jQuery. **Problem: I have three component in the container. Initially all font color are black. I would like to change the font color according to the class name of each div.**

I able to change two of them while fail to change all. My code are belows:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="Red">old content</div>
        <div class="Black">old content</div>
        <div class="Blue">old content</div>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container div')
        .delay(10000)
        .css("color","Blue")
        .delay(10000)
        .filter(".Red")
        .css("color", "Red")
        .delay(10000)
        .filter(".Black")
        .css("color", "Black");
    });
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.container div').each(function(i, el)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).css("color", $(this).attr('class'));
    }, i * 1000);
});
```

**Explanation:**

1. Loop through all divs inside container
2. For each div, set the color to the class name after 1000 milliseconds multiplied by it's index in the set of divs

Comment: don't create your own solution with unwanted functions from what the OP wanted. he might want to learn using `delay`.Also there can be olverlaps . your solution is NOT  pure a then b then c. it's do a , calc time ( regardless a) and then do b. it's not the same

Comment: You should really know the difference between using setTimeout and `.delay`

Comment: `don't create your own solution with unwanted functions from what the OP wanted`. Unwanted functions? OP has asked for a solution, and didn't explicitly ask for the use of delay.

Comment: He had started with a very valid solution. you changed it completly for no reason. ( and incorrect one also)

Comment: You've mentioned the different between `setTimeout` and `delay` multiple times now. In this scenario, my useage of setTimeout is correct, your use of delay is unnecessary.

Comment: `He started with a very valid solution`. It didn't work. What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: never mind. you didnt want to show him where he was wrong and to fix his solution , instead , you created incorrect similar code.

Comment: Please clarify how I'm incorrect. His solution was incorrect, and it was not scalable. I've helped him a great deal by showing him an alternative approach. Please be sure to read the following: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem And be less ignorant

Comment: for example : if xxx is taking time `setTimeout(function(){
   xxx()
    }, i * 1000);` - then your solution is not accurate while myne is. becuase you dont care about the execution time of `xxx` . My solution does wait xxx to complete. yours  - NOT.

Comment: How is it not precise? `i` is reliable, it is incremented by 1 on each iteration. Nobody should explicilty list strings in this case, you should know better. If OP adds `yellow`, your code is useless, mine still works.

Comment: read my comment again (_you dont care about the execution time of xxx . My solution does wait xxx to complete. yours - NOT._)

Comment: Read mine. I'm aware of the differences of setTimeout and delay, but you must pick one that's most applicable to the requirements in hand, I have. OP has not mentioned any form of transition or used jQuery animate. Until he does, delay is unnecessary. How long, exactly, does your browser take to assign a new font color to a single element?

Comment: You want to  ignore the situation. tomorrow he will faced more complex scenario - and instead of teaching him how to wait exactly  1 sec ( as he wanted !) {well not exactly - but the point is after xxx is finished} - you round corners. this Debate  is unnecessary. don't forget that his question might be simplification of a more complex senario

Comment: A few comments ago you implied we shouldn't even be 'teaching' him and should just run with what he already has? Now you want me to teach him? You've used delay, filer AND queue. No need. Keep it simple. It only needs a loop and a timeout. If tomorrow his "complex scenario" is to add the colour "brown" to his list of divs, your code is useless to him. You haven't addressed this yet, I've mentioned it 3 times. You're bitter because your solution is verbose and less concise than somebody with considerably less rep than you.

Comment: REgarding verbose - I agree and Im posting a new one. reagarding the other stuff - your solution is not accurate

Comment: Nice to see you avoid the issue of new colours....again. My solution is 100% accurate. If (and ONLY if) OP introduces CSS transitions, he can adapt the timeout amount. No problem. Looking forward to seeing your 'new one'. Next time, try and take criticism and little more positively.

Comment: As I said ,, I'm posting an edit with solution to be dynamic colors. why arent you reading the comments ?

Comment: Read the comment yourself, you didn't address that, you addressed how verbose yours is. You didn't mention the use of explicitly name classes.

Comment: deleting my answer . dont have time for dynamic elements right now.

Comment: Hi Both, Thanks for introducing me setTimeOut and .each option for me. While it seems i have problem to run the code. There is one point i would like to clarify is that i should include above code inside the $(document).ready(function(){}); Indeed above question is inspired by the example from jQuery Cookbook.

Comment: Where you want the code I've written to execute will determine where you put it. If you'd like it to run as soon as the document is ready then yes - put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` (or at least a call inside document ready to a function that includes the code I've written)